# file-loader image full path

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

How can I use the file-loader to save full images paths?

my loader cfg

```
test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/, 
     use: [ 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=images/'  ]
```

img path `src/images/1.jpg and src/images/section/2.jpg`

On production I get `dist/images/1.jpg` and `dist/images/2.jpg`

I tried to change to `use: [ 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext] ]`

But got on production `dist/src/images/1.jpg` and `dist/src/images/section/2.jpg`

How do I change my loader setting to get on production `dist/images/1.jpg` and `dist/images/section/2.jpg` ?

```
"file-loader": "^0.11.2"
"webpack": "^3.5.5"
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe publicPath will help
https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`[path]` placeholder](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#placeholders) is the path relative to the context. By default that is the root of your project, more specifically the directory where you run webpack from, unless you've configured the [`context` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context).

The `file-loader` itself also accepts a [`context` option](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#context), which allows to you change that behaviour just for the given rule. In your case you would set it to `src`.

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        context: 'src'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```